# Can "nice" when used about people mean "beautiful"? Can a nice woman be ugly?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Can *nice* **used with a person** be about his/her look?
Can I use *a nice woman* and mean *(sexually) attractive*, like in *a beautiful woman*? Or is it always only about their behaviour and kindness, when used about people?

And more specific: can *a nice woman* be *ugly*? :)

> **nice**, *adj*
>
> - giving pleasure or joy : good and enjoyable
> - attractive or of good quality
> - kind, polite, and friendly

Source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nice

Comment: It can be short for "looking nice", of course. "How do you think she looks?" "Nice!" But maybe that's pushing it a bit.

Comment: The usual sense when applied to a person is as a character / demeanour descriptor (see [Cobuild](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Nice) (2) ). However, context can make the appearance-descriptor sense obvious, as in 'Oooh – _she_'s nice!

Comment: No, it's not **always** only about behavior and kindness. When wanting to eliminate ambiguity, some might use _nice-looking_ to clarify, but even that can mean either _well dressed_ or  _sexually attractive_ (or both, or something else, such as _well-groomed_).

Answer (score 3):

So says the dictionary.

However, for practical purposes, to say that someone is "nice", sometimes (of course depending on the context) may be just an euphemism to say that he/she is **not** attractive  :-)

http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=108804781

Comment: Something like when you say "your dress is interesting" to avoid a more unpleasant answer :)